# sql query left join records missing

Tags: php, sql, join

```
SELECT 
    a.customers_id, b.name, b.office, b.username, a.serial_number, a.id
FROM 
    user_assets AS a
left JOIN 
    customers AS b ON 
        a.customers_id = b.id 
WHERE NOT 
        (b.username LIKE 'Warehouse') 
    AND (serial_number LIKE 'R8%' 
        OR serial_number LIKE 'LR%' 
        OR serial_number LIKE 'R9%')
GROUP BY
    a.customers_id
HAVING (COUNT(a.customers_id) >=2);
```

the query should find which users have multiple computers. only one record per user is showing though, how can i show all associated rows from the serial_number column?

**EDIT**:

removed `and a.customers_id = a.customers_id` as it was something i was trying, and `$by` as its uneeded for this question

Comment: Why did you put this condition `a.customers_id = a.customers_id` in the `JOIN` condition?

Comment: What's the purpose of `a.customers_id = a.customers_id` in the `ON` clause?

Comment: i removed that part, i was trying something and forgot to remove it before posting

Comment: Would you care to show some example output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need `left join` and `group by`, but need simple inner join with a subquery in where-clause:

```
select b.customers_id, b.name, b.office, b.username, a.serial_number, a.id
from user_assets a, customers b 
WHERE a.customers_id = b.id 
  and b.username != 'Warehouse' 
  and (serial_number LIKE 'R8%' or serial_number LIKE 'LR%' or serial_number LIKE 'R9%')
  and (select count(1) from user_assets a1 
       where a1.customers_id=b.id
       and (serial_number LIKE 'R8%' or serial_number LIKE 'LR%' or serial_number LIKE 'R9%')  
      ) >= 2
```

Also you should consider creating and using directory table `asset_types` instead of such `like`-predicates on serial numbers. It would be more effective and a much better practise in general.

Comment: thank you very much, this is pretty much what i needed. for some reason though its returning results outside of the like conditions, for example a user with an asset with a serial number starting with something other than r8, r9 or lr are now showing up

Comment: Maybe you should include the same like-predicate inside inner query too? Do such serial number means that asset is computer?

Comment: ill try that. the extra results are users that have multiple assets, but the extra asset is not a computer, so i want to disclude those from the results. i want to display users who have multiple assets but only if all of assets have serials starting with r8, r9 and lr

Answer (score 0):

The use of `GROUP BY` - as its name implies -  groups the results (in your case by `user_assets`' `customer_id`). Leave out the `GROUP BY` and it should return every single record that matches your criteria.

I guess what you've really wanted is a way to group the records by their respective customers. You should use a `ORDER BY a.customer_id`, then process the records in your application logic.

**EDIT** A working example would be:

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.customers_id,           
       a.serial_number,
       b.name,
       b.office,
       b.username
  FROM user_assets AS a
  LEFT JOIN customers AS b
    ON a.customers_id = b.id 
 WHERE b.username != 'Warehouse'
   AND ( a.serial_number LIKE 'R8%'
    OR a.serial_number LIKE 'LR%'
    OR a.serial_number LIKE 'R9%' )
 ORDER BY a.customer_id
```

Example output:

```
+----+--------------+---------------+-----+
| id | customers_id | serial_number | ... |
+----+--------------+---------------+-----+
|  3 |           11 | R8-xyz        | ... |
|  4 |           13 | R9-abc        | ... |
|  5 |           13 | R8-xyz        | ... |
|  6 |           13 | LR-abc        | ... |
| .. |           .. | ...           | ... |
| 37 |           21 | LR-abc        | ... |
| 38 |           21 | LR-def        | ... |
+----+--------------+---------------+-----+
```

Comment: thanks, i tried that but some had some issues, once i got it working it was returning even less results than before

Comment: Once you get rid of the `GROUP BY`, you would have to remove the `HAVING CLAUSE` as well.